# Не отрисосвывается кнопка, написанная с помощью pygame

Tags: python, button, pygame

Еле как смог собрать код и вроде как подогнать его, что бы получалось создать UI для небольшого проекта. Хотел добавить кнопку, но сколько не бьюсь, никак не могу понять, почему не отрисовывается.

Вот код:

```
    import pygame, sys, pygame_gui

pygame.init()

class Btn1():
    def __init__(self, image, pos, text_input, font, base_color, hov_color):
        self.image = image
        self.x_pos = pos[0]
        self.y_pos = pos[1]
        self.font = font
        self.base_color, self.hov_color = base_color, hov_color
        self.text_input = text_input
        self.text = self.font.render(self.text_input, True, self.base_color)
        if self.image is None:
            self.image = self.text
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(self.x_pos, self.y_pos))
        self.text_rect = self.text.get_rect(center=(self.x_pos, self.y_pos))

    def update(self, screen):
        if self.image is not None:
            screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.text, self.text_rect)

    def checkForInput(self, position):
        if position[0] in range(self.rect.left, self.rect.right) and position[1] in range(self.rect.top, self.rect.bottom):
            return True
        return False

    def changeColor(self, position):
        if position[0] in range(self.rect.left, self.rect.right) and position[1] in range(self.rect.top, self.rect.bottom):
            self.text = self.font.render(self.text_input, True, self.hov_color)
        else:
            self.text = self.font.render(self.text_input, True, self.base_color)

def get_font(size):
    return pygame.font.Font(None, size)

WIDTH, HEIGHT, = 1600, 900
Width2, Height2 = 350,250
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Счётчик слов")
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
supbase_font = pygame.font.Font(None,56)
user_text_1 = 'Введите путь к файлу, в котором будет выполняться подсчёт:'
user_text_2 = 'Введите путь к файлу, в который будет записываться результат подсчёта:'
user_text_3 = 'СЧЁТЧИК СЛОВ 3000 УЛЬТРА PRO MAX SLIM SHADY'

CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
MANAGER = pygame_gui.UIManager((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

TEXT_INPUT_1 = pygame_gui.elements.UITextEntryLine(relative_rect=pygame.Rect((350,275),(900,50)), manager=MANAGER, object_id="#main_text_entry")
TEXT_INPUT_2 = pygame_gui.elements.UITextEntryLine(relative_rect=pygame.Rect((350,375),(900,50)), manager=MANAGER, object_id="#main_text_entry")

while True:
    MENU_MOUSE_POS = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    submit_btn = Btn1(image=pygame.image.load("images/grrec_sub.png"), pos=(400, 400), text_input="SUBMIT",
                      font=get_font(75), base_color="blue", hov_color="gray23")
    for btn2 in [submit_btn]:
        btn2.changeColor(MENU_MOUSE_POS)
        btn2.update(SCREEN)
    UI_REFRESH_RATE = CLOCK.tick(60)/1000

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame_gui.UI_TEXT_ENTRY_FINISHED and event.ui_object_id == "#main_text_entry":
            r = TEXT_INPUT_1.get_text()
            res = TEXT_INPUT_2.get_text()
            print(r)
            print(res)

        MANAGER.process_events(event)
    MANAGER.update(UI_REFRESH_RATE)

    SCREEN.fill("gray10")
    text_sur1 = base_font.render(user_text_1, True, (255, 255, 255))
    SCREEN.blit(text_sur1, (350,250))
    text_sur2 = base_font.render(user_text_2, True, (255, 255, 255))
    SCREEN.blit(text_sur2, (350, 350))
    text_sur3 = supbase_font.render(user_text_3, True, "crimson")
    SCREEN.blit(text_sur3, (300, 100))

    MANAGER.draw_ui(SCREEN)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: А зачем вы кнопку создаете в цикле while?